# Can't rescale image with css

Tags: html, css

I've searched on a lot of topics and I didn't found the solution...

I'm just trying to scale my image to fit into my div but it isn't.

HTML :

```
<div class="slideshow-image slideshow-active">
  <img src="assets/images/securityBreach1.png">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.slideshow-image {
text-align: center;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've already tried to play with `max-width/height`, `width/height` and `object-fit:content` but nothing seems work.

[Here's](http://ghosttv.000webhostapp.com/security_breach.php) the website page if you want (see the slideshow part) :

[image: Picture are better than words]

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following?

```
.slideshow-image img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Ok that was my mistake, I was convinced the class was on the img itself... Thank you.